# I'm trying to loop through all files in directory & its subfolders, get each file's text content & return an array of text content

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, function, loops

I have already created a `function` to recursively go through a `directory`(also its sub-folders) and retrieve all the files with a specific extension.

Now I have created another `function` that will take an `array` of the files retrieved, access their content & return another `array` with the text content of each file.

This is code for the `function` to get & return each file's text content:

```
const readFileContent = files => {
  files.forEach(file => {
    return fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(data); // print all the text for each file
      return [data];
    });
  });
};

const allFilesTextContent = readFileContent(allSpecFiles);

console.log(allFilesTextContent); // prints undefined
```

However, when I store the `function` in another `variable` & print it, I get `undefined`. If I print inside the loop I get the text content of each file. I have also try to [push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to a new `array` like so:

```
const readFileContent = files => {
  let results = [];
  files.forEach(file => {
    fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(data); // print all the text for each file
      results.push(data);
    });
  });
  return results;
};

const allFilesTextContent = readFileContent(allSpecFiles);
console.log(allFilesTextContent); // print an empty array - []
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You cannot access `async function` result outside the `callback`

Comment: Can you provide me with a working solution @ShivamSood  I have been trying to wrap my code in `async/await` but no luck far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing `forEach` with `map` and using an `async` function.

#### Sequential resolution

```js
import {promises as fs} from "fs";

const readFileContent = async (files) => {
  return await Promise.map(files, async (file) => {
    return await fs.readFile(file, 'utf8');
  });
};
```

#### Concurrent resolution

```js
import {promises as fs} from "fs";

const readFileContent = async (files) => {
  return await Promise.all(
    files.map( (file) => fs.readFile(file, 'utf8') )
  );
};
```

Comment: What's the equivalent of this line `import {promises as fs, constants} from "fs";` with `require()` instead? Also, why we need `constants` if it's never used? @emi

Comment: Sorry about `constants`. Just copied from an own project.

Comment: The `requiere` version of the promisified version of `fs` would be `const fs = require("fs/promises");`

Comment: Added an alternative answer, with parallel/concurrent resolution.

Comment: If this answered your question, please, mark the answer as the accepted one apart from up voting it.

Comment: Sorry, bro, it doesn't. Otherwise, I would have done it for sure! Don't worry about that

Comment: What problems do arise?

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful, let me know if you face any errors

```
const fs = require("fs").promises;

const readFileContent = async (files) => {
  try {
    let results = [];
    for (const file of files) {
      results = await fs.readFile(file, "utf8");
    }
    return results;
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
};

readFileContent(allSpecFiles)
  .then((data) => console.log(data))
  .catch((error) => console.error(error));
```

This is `async/await` version as it's more cleaner and readable but the basic idea is that whatever function you run in `async/await` you will get `promise` back which you need to resolve either using `then/catch` or another `async/await`

Comment: You should do `results.push( ... )` instead of `results = ...`, or you are only going to save the last `result`. This can also be solved using `Promise.map()` instead of the `for( ... of ...)` loop.

Comment: You are correct, I just whipped up an example, improvements are definitely needed.